# Grunt usemin not updating html on watch

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Im trying to modify the a grunt setup made with the yeoman webapp-generator.

The build works fine, but when I watch, the css links in _laytout.html wrapped in usemin comments aren't updated to the compiled src in .tmp/styles/.

The main issue here might be that I've set it up with MAMP and aren't using the `grunt server` command.

Feel free to get the repo here: https://github.com/spoeken/generator-craft

All of the project files are within app/

The grunt file looks like this:

```
// Generated on 2014-04-10 using generator-webapp 0.4.8
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    config: {
        // Configurable paths
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'public',
        craft: 'craft/templates'
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['bowerInstall']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        jstest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['test:watch']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        html : {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:craft']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= config.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        templates: '<%= config.dist %>/templates',
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },

    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= config.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= config.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= config.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= config.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    bowerInstall: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/templates/_layout.html'],
            ignorePath: '<%= config.app %>/',
            exclude: ['<%= config.app %>/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
        },
        sass: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            ignorePath: '<%= config.app %>/bower_components/'
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= config.app %>/templates/_layout.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
        },
        html: '<%= config.app %>/templates/_layout.html',
        css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //     dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                    'templates/{,*/}*.html',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        craft: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.dist %>/templates',
                dest: '<%= config.craft %>',
                src: [
                    '{,*/}*.html'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },

    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
        devFile: '<%= config.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
        files: [
            '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
        ],
        uglify: true
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass:server',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:test',
            'autoprefixer'
        ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'copy:craft',
    'clean:templates',
    //'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```